# Mutexes around single word read and writes

Tags: embedded, cpu-word, mutex

If you have a multi-threaded application with a word variable shared between threads (ie - 32-bit data type on a 32-bit system), is it necessary to protect reads and writes to that word with a mutex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than talk about caches, multicore, out-of-order execution, etc. I'll just offer a simple example to illustrate why you'd want to use a mutex (or some other mutual exclusion technique, e.g. interrupt manipulation, etc.)

In order to increment a variable by one - at least on most architectures I deal with these days - you have to read the value from memory to a register, adjust the value in the register, and write it back to memory.  Suppose we have 2 threads, high-priority A, and low priority B.  Take this scenario:

- Thread B reads "x" from memory into a register (value is 5).
- Thread B increments the register to value 6.
- Thread A pre-empts Thread B.
- Thread A reads "x" into a register (value is still 5 in memory, right?).
- Thread A increments register to value 6.
- Thread A writes value 6 back to memory
- Thread A goes to sleep.
- Thread B wakes up, and writes its register value 6 back to memory.

**Now both threads incremented the value, but it only went up by one.**

If this was the elevator floor number, the number of heart beats sensed, or the space shuttle countdown value (OK, that would be a decrement), we might have ourselves a problem.

Note that there are some architectures (usually CISC) that can do this increment operation atomically, it's better to not make this assumption (hello, portability & correctness).

Note: In some cases - ***but don't do this*** - you can get away without a mutex if you have one writer & multiple readers.  For example, maybe an ISR increments a tick count or whatever, and other threads/tasks come by & read it every so often.

I guess the point I want to make is that **it's always a good idea to protect shared data**, even if you think you can get away without it.  If you want to "go commando", you REALLY have to know what you're doing, and even then, the same code could break tomorrow when it's ported to a new architecture.

Comment: This was the crux of the discussion in our group.  However, I don't think putting protection around the read/write of your variable would make a difference here.  You'd have to do 'take' 'read' 'increment' 'write' 'give', taking the mutex out of your read/write functions to do this.  If you 'take' 'read' 'give' 'increment' 'take' 'write' 'give', putting a mutex in your read and write functions, the same preemption problem occurs if preempted before or after your 'increment' operation.  I think this is always going to be a problem with 2 writers, and is the reason I asked this question.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need to take-read-modify-write-give.  The other pattern, as you note, simply does not work.  Read-modify-write must be treated as a single transaction, and protected as a unit.  If your code has separate reader and writer calls, you're operating at the wrong abstraction/encapsulation level for a shared resource.  That needs to be addressed, potentially by adding a separate "modify" call if you need to preserve the bare "read" call, or by refactoring in some way appropriate to the particular application.

Answer (score 2):

In general, **yes**, you should synchronize access with a mutex. Even if you believe a write to a memory location will be "atomic", the CPU may re-order instructions that read and write to that memory, causing unwanted behavior. Also, on a multi-core or mutli-CPU system, a write to a shared memory location may not be immediately visible to other cores/CPUs without synchronization.

For more information see the Wikipedia article for [Memory Barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

Comment: Does this only occur with optimization enabled?  Reading that link, it seems like the 'volatile' keyword on the data would prevent this entirely, eliminating the need for a mutex.  This is a single-core CPU, so there are no multi-core issues here.  I know multi-word variables (arrays, doubles, strings) necessitate mutexes, but I'm still not convinced single word accesses are necessary.